# Dynamic carousel from object

Tags: angular, carousel, bootstrap-5

I have the below carousel that is populated from an object pictures:

```
            <div class="carousel-inner mb-5">

                <div *ngFor="let pic of pictures; let i = index">
                    <div *ngIf="i == 0">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src={{pic.path}} class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="i > 0">
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img src={{pic.path}} class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(121).webp" class="d-block w-100"
                        alt="..." />
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(31).webp" class="d-block w-100"
                        alt="..." />
                </div> -->
            </div>
```

My issue is I want the thumbnail to slide to specific image on click:

```
            <!-- Thumbnails -->
            <div class="slider carousel-indicators position-absolute">
                <div *ngFor="let img of pictures, let i=index">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicatorsLeft" data-bs-slide-to= {{i.toString()}}
                        class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src={{img.path}} class="img-fluid" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicatorsLeft" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                    aria-label="Slide 2">
                    <img class="d-block w-100"
                        src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(121).webp"
                        class="img-fluid" />
                </button>

                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicatorsLeft" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                    aria-label="Slide 3">
                    <img class="d-block w-100"
                        src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Others/Carousel-thumbs/img%20(31).webp"
                        class="img-fluid" />
                </button> -->
            </div>
```

I have tried to set an index in the ng for and pass it to data-bs-slide-to={{i.toString()}}, but it does not allow me to parse dynamic values to data-bs-slide-to. Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-carousel-bsaqnu) is an example. Your HTML looks good. Here is it a with dots (it can be your thumbnail image). The index will be set in the `ngFor` loop.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container slider">
  <div [@slideAnimation]="currentIndex">
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="slides" let-slide let-i="index">
      <img class="slide slide-animation nonDraggableImage"
           *ngIf="isCurrentSlideIndex(i)"
           (swiperight)="nextSlide()" (swipeleft)="prevSlide()"
           [src]="slide.image">
    </ng-template>
  </div>

  <button class="arrow prev" (click)="nextSlide()"></button>
  <button class="arrow next" (click)="prevSlide()"></button>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="dots">
        <li class="dot" *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index;">
          <span [ngClass]="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex(i)}"
             (click)="setCurrentSlideIndex(i);">{{slide.description}}</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
  constructor() {
    this.preloadImages();
  }

  preloadImages() {
    this.slides.forEach(slide => {
      (new Image()).src = slide.image;
    });
    console.log('slides: ', this.slides)
  }

  setCurrentSlideIndex(index) {
    this.currentIndex = index;
  }

  isCurrentSlideIndex(index) {
    return this.currentIndex === index;
  }

  prevSlide() {
    this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex < this.slides.length - 1) ? ++this.currentIndex : 0;
  }

  nextSlide() {
    this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex > 0) ? --this.currentIndex : this.slides.length - 1;
  }
```

Here we gave the index to the `setCurrentSlideIndex()` method and the rest does the animation:

**TS Code**

```
export const slideAnimation = trigger('slideAnimation', [
  transition(':increment', group([
    query(':enter', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      }),
      animate('0.5s ease-out', style('*'))
    ]),
    query(':leave', [
      animate('0.5s ease-out', style({
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }))
    ])
  ])),
  transition(':decrement', group([
    query(':enter', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }),
      animate('0.5s ease-out', style('*'))
    ]),
    query(':leave', [
      animate('0.5s ease-out', style({
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      }))
    ])
  ]))
]);
```

Then, I think, you have all you want.

Comment: Great. You can set my post as answer, too. Very thx.